# Algorithm suggestions for solving Euler-Lagrange equations numerically

Tags: python, numerical-methods, pde

For my coursework I've been told to write an algorithm in Python to solve the Euler-Lagrange equations with Dirichlet boundary conditions.

For reasons I don't understand we have only studied finite difference methods yet (very briefly) in lectures. I was wondering if I should start with that algorithm, or would you recommend another method that is not too complicated but would be more efficient?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean a general solution method for the equation `d/dt(dL(x,v)/dv)=dL/dx` for `v=dx/dt` for some given function $L(x,v)$? Are you allowed to use `scpiy` and especially `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp`.

Comment: Hey thanks for you comment. I'm meant to code the algorithm from scratch not use an existing package.

Comment: @TheMysteriousPigeon, but can you be more specific about "Euler-Lagrange", as the term may be used to mean different things in different fields, though I tend to agree with LutzL comment.

Comment: @TheMysteriousPigeon, what do you expect to get from "not too complicated but would be more efficient"?  FD method is not complicated and is efficient.  There are methods like finite element, boundary element, ode solvers.  They are all complicated in their own way.  FD works well for the type of problem you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Shooting methods, when they work, are fast and accurate. There
are some problems for which the BVP is well-posed but the IVP
used in the shooting method is not (e.g. the IVP has infinite
solutions for some values of z).
That's chapter 13 page 13 of your lecture notes